# How to work on an external developer's project using Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

**Me** - Front End web developer with an ok working knowledge of writing VB.NET code but I have never built a .NET project from scratch using Visual Studio.

**External developer** - Experienced VB.NET developer but completely new to version control and TFS. Also extremely cheap and prone to infuriatingly poor programming practices. He does things that make you bang your head on the table.

### Background

Our external developer has coded our site but over the last few years I have been tweaking aspects of pages and have managed to learn quite a bit of VB.NET along the way. He has **never** used source control and I don't think he's ever had to work with another developer before.

Up until now he has maintained a local copy of the website. He makes changes to this local copy and when he wants us to test it he uploads the relevant files to our dev server. I have no experience of Visual Studio projects/solutions so if I have made tweaks to things I have edited the aspx/asxh/config files in my preferred editor and then uploaded them to the dev server. If everything works correctly I ask him to download them from the server so he can update his local copy.

I have been maintaining a local git repository of the website for the last 2 years. If he makes a change I check it in.

Obviously this is a nightmare to work with so we have now insisted that he starts using version control. I recommended GIT but he has decided to use TFS.

He has now put his solution and all the files into TFS. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 and successfully connected to TFS. I have mapped the files from source control to my own workspace but I am now at a loss as to what to do next.

### Questions

1. As soon as I open the .sln file he has uploaded it says I have checked out the file and made changes. When I check the diff it seems to be because I am using a newer version of Visual Studio than he is. Does the .sln file need to be in version control? Or are we suppose to maintain our own versions of the .sln file and simply check in everything else?
2. If I try and build the project it fails because the web.config is set up for his machine and not mine. How can we maintain 3 versions of the web.config file? One for my local, one for his, and one for our dev/live environments?

I am not convinced he will have added the project to TFS correctly because he's never used it before. This is basically the blind leading the blind.

Answer (score 0):

*Question 1:*

You need to put the .sln file in version control. Before check out the .sln file, please do a "get latest" step, which will make sure both of you are working on the latest version. When you try to check your local version in the server, and he had uploaded his local version in the server. You may have to solve conflicts before the check in.

*Question 2:*

You should build your project and published the website on the server. The build agent will only maintain one version of the web.config file. If he has built the project with his web.config. And you want to build the project again with your web.config, the build agent will delete the previous web.config and pull down your version. Then build the project with your's web.config.

Moreover, if both of you are not similar with TFS. Suggest you taking a look at below MSDN link which related to source control and build.

- [Use Team Foundation Version Control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/overview)
- [TFS Vnext Build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview)